# What to call loading old data into new classes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create tools to make development easier, but have trouble finding resources about this problem.

A budget application is under development and the main class, Month, frequently has new features added. The application is concurrently being used, leaving behind a directory of saved Months (as pickled files).

This is a problem when working with old data: loading saved data creates an *older version* of the Month. I'd like to use new features to manipulate the data, but the old Month object wasn't created with the necessary methods.

Is there a term for the problem of initiating the newest version of a class (application/anything) with old data?

Comment: I don't even understand what your question is so can you clarify?

Comment: Don't pickle objects for that use. Pickling is meant for exactly the opposite of your use case: Get the data and the behaviour of an object from the time it was pickled. Serialize the data-fields into json or something like that and add tests to make sure that "old" versions get sensible default values when de-serializing.

Comment: If you keep a copy of the old classes you can use that for versioning. For example, Month v2 can be a subclass of Month v1, Month v3 can be a subclass of Month v2, and so on. You may need some custom logic for going up a version if you want to convert v1 to v2, etc.